# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.activation.DataHandler in android

Tags: android

I am making a email sending application in android phone. For that I included two jar file `activation. jar` and `mail.jar`. But when I run this application and try to send the mail, I got following error on `LogCat`.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.activation.DataHandler
```

I am new to android. so I am not able to figure out this issue. please Help me. Thanks

Comment: have imported DataHandler class

Answer (score 62, accepted):

There is an [Android-friendly port of javamail](http://code.google.com/p/javamail-android) which you should be using. There are three libraries that you need to include in your app: mail.jar, activation.jar, and additionnal.jar(sic). It looks like you are missing something that the activation library depends on, and this could be because you are not using the Android port of this library.

I have used the Android-friendly version of javamail successfully in a project, and it works really well.

Comment: Hey Thanks Mark... I was not including additional.jar. Thanks for the support

Comment: I wasn't including activation.jar and additional.jar files

Comment: Is this in maven somewhere so that I could just add it as a library in Android Studio?

Comment: Now that google code is shutting down, will the project be moved to eg. github? I've sent the question to Alexandre Thiel who posted the project on google code.

Comment: Unfortunately it's GPL, which makes it useless for pretty much everyone who isn't playing.

Answer (score 10):

The [JavaMail API Reference Implementation](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/) version 1.5.5 and later have built in support for [Android](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/Android) and include support for [OAuth2](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/OAuth2).

Per the documentation:

> Android does not provide a Java Compatible runtime and so can't run the standard JavaMail distribution. Instead, a special version of JavaMail is available for Android. This special version of JavaMail depends on a special version of the JavaBeans Activation Framework.
>
> You can try out this version by adding the following to your build.gradle file for your Android application:

```
 android {
     packagingOptions {
         pickFirst 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt' // picks the JavaMail license file
     }
 }

 repositories { 
     jcenter()
     maven {
         url "https://maven.java.net/content/groups/public/"
     }
 }

 dependencies {
     compile 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.5.5'
     compile 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.5.5'
 }
```

Starting with [JavaMail 1.6.0](https://github.com/javaee/javamail/issues/285):

> JavaMail for Android requires at least Android API level 19, which corresponds to Android KitKat, currently the oldest supported version of Android.

Comment: use the same dependencies `android-mail` and `android-activiation` if writing a generic library that works on server jvm as well INSTEAD OF `javax.mail` and `javax.activation-api`

Answer (score 0):

If you are Build an E-mail sender java AWT app or Android App you need to use 3 jar files:

- `activation.jar`   (which contain classes like Mime.class)
- `javax_mail.jar`   (which contain classes like  like Session.class)
- `additional.jar`   (which contain awt files)

Link : https://code.google.com/archive/p/javamail-android/downloads

I am commenting on this stuff because I struggled too hard with this  `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.javax.activation.DataHandler`
while   creating my java mail_sender app, and then I found  that I missed to add additional jar file.