# How to solve following Log cat Error

Tags: android

I create peoject which send email. but when i run it, it run but when i click on send
button it show "send application has been stop" and display error in LogCat.
Log cat error are following.
Pls tell me what is wrong in project.

```
02-16 23:33:51.162: D/dalvikvm(587): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
02-16 23:33:53.511: D/gralloc_goldfish(587): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
02-16 23:33:57.772: I/dalvikvm(587): Failed resolving Ljavax/activation/DataHandler; interface 176 'Ljava/awt/datatransfer/Transferable;'
02-16 23:33:57.772: W/dalvikvm(587): Link of class 'Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;' failed
02-16 23:33:57.801: E/dalvikvm(587): Could not find class 'javax.activation.DataHandler', referenced from method san.sendmail.improsys.GMailSender.sendMail
02-16 23:33:57.801: W/dalvikvm(587): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 351 (Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;) in Lsan/sendmail/improsys/GMailSender;
02-16 23:33:57.813: D/dalvikvm(587): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0008
02-16 23:33:57.852: I/dalvikvm(587): Failed resolving Ljavax/activation/DataHandler; interface 176 'Ljava/awt/datatransfer/Transferable;'
02-16 23:33:57.852: W/dalvikvm(587): Link of class 'Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;' failed
02-16 23:33:57.871: D/dalvikvm(587): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x06d7 at 0x15 in Lsan/sendmail/improsys/GMailSender;.sendMail
02-16 23:33:57.962: I/dalvikvm(587): Failed resolving Ljavax/activation/DataHandler; interface 176 'Ljava/awt/datatransfer/Transferable;'
02-16 23:33:57.962: W/dalvikvm(587): Link of class 'Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;' failed
02-16 23:33:57.962: W/dalvikvm(587): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;)
02-16 23:33:57.981: I/dalvikvm(587): Failed resolving Ljavax/activation/DataHandler; interface 176 'Ljava/awt/datatransfer/Transferable;'
02-16 23:33:57.992: W/dalvikvm(587): Link of class 'Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;' failed
02-16 23:33:57.992: I/dalvikvm(587): Could not find method javax.activation.DataHandler.getContent, referenced from method javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.getContent
02-16 23:33:57.992: W/dalvikvm(587): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1760: Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;.getContent ()Ljava/lang/Object;
02-16 23:33:57.992: D/dalvikvm(587): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0004
02-16 23:33:58.012: I/dalvikvm(587): Failed resolving Ljavax/activation/DataHandler; interface 176 'Ljava/awt/datatransfer/Transferable;'
02-16 23:33:58.012: W/dalvikvm(587): Link of class 'Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;' failed
02-16 23:33:58.023: I/dalvikvm(587): Failed resolving Ljavax/activation/DataHandler; interface 176 'Ljava/awt/datatransfer/Transferable;'
02-16 23:33:58.023: W/dalvikvm(587): Link of class 'Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;' failed
02-16 23:33:58.023: E/dalvikvm(587): Could not find class 'javax.activation.DataHandler', referenced from method javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.getDataHandler
02-16 23:33:58.032: W/dalvikvm(587): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 351 (Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;) in Ljavax/mail/internet/MimeMessage;
02-16 23:33:58.032: D/dalvikvm(587): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0005
02-16 23:33:58.042: I/dalvikvm(587): Failed resolving Ljavax/activation/DataHandler; interface 176 'Ljava/awt/datatransfer/Transferable;'
02-16 23:33:58.042: W/dalvikvm(587): Link of class 'Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;' failed
02-16 23:33:58.051: I/dalvikvm(587): Failed resolving Ljavax/activation/DataHandler; interface 176 'Ljava/awt/datatransfer/Transferable;'
02-16 23:33:58.051: W/dalvikvm(587): Link of class 'Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;' failed
02-16 23:33:58.051: W/dalvikvm(587): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;)
02-16 23:33:58.071: I/dalvikvm(587): Failed resolving Ljavax/activation/DataHandler; interface 176 'Ljava/awt/datatransfer/Transferable;'
02-16 23:33:58.071: W/dalvikvm(587): Link of class 'Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;' failed
02-16 23:33:58.071: W/dalvikvm(587): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;)
02-16 23:33:58.082: I/dalvikvm(587): Failed resolving Ljavax/activation/DataHandler; interface 176 'Ljava/awt/datatransfer/Transferable;'
02-16 23:33:58.082: W/dalvikvm(587): Link of class 'Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;' failed
02-16 23:33:58.082: I/dalvikvm(587): Could not find method javax.activation.DataHandler.getInputStream, referenced from method javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.getInputStream
02-16 23:33:58.082: W/dalvikvm(587): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1764: Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;.getInputStream ()Ljava/io/InputStream;
02-16 23:33:58.082: D/dalvikvm(587): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0004
02-16 23:33:58.124: I/dalvikvm(587): Failed resolving Ljavax/activation/DataHandler; interface 176 'Ljava/awt/datatransfer/Transferable;'
02-16 23:33:58.124: W/dalvikvm(587): Link of class 'Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;' failed
02-16 23:33:58.124: E/dalvikvm(587): Could not find class 'javax.activation.DataHandler', referenced from method javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.setContent
02-16 23:33:58.124: W/dalvikvm(587): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 351 (Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;) in Ljavax/mail/internet/MimeMessage;
02-16 23:33:58.133: D/dalvikvm(587): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
02-16 23:33:58.133: I/dalvikvm(587): Failed resolving Ljavax/activation/DataHandler; interface 176 'Ljava/awt/datatransfer/Transferable;'
02-16 23:33:58.133: W/dalvikvm(587): Link of class 'Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;' failed
02-16 23:33:58.142: E/dalvikvm(587): Could not find class 'javax.activation.DataHandler', referenced from method javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.setContent
02-16 23:33:58.142: W/dalvikvm(587): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 351 (Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;) in Ljavax/mail/internet/MimeMessage;
02-16 23:33:58.142: D/dalvikvm(587): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
02-16 23:33:58.151: I/dalvikvm(587): Failed resolving Ljavax/activation/DataHandler; interface 176 'Ljava/awt/datatransfer/Transferable;'
02-16 23:33:58.151: W/dalvikvm(587): Link of class 'Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;' failed
02-16 23:33:58.162: W/dalvikvm(587): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;)
02-16 23:33:58.182: I/dalvikvm(587): Failed resolving Ljavax/activation/DataHandler; interface 176 'Ljava/awt/datatransfer/Transferable;'
02-16 23:33:58.182: W/dalvikvm(587): Link of class 'Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;' failed
02-16 23:33:58.271: I/dalvikvm(587): Failed resolving Ljavax/activation/DataHandler; interface 176 'Ljava/awt/datatransfer/Transferable;'
02-16 23:33:58.271: W/dalvikvm(587): Link of class 'Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;' failed
02-16 23:33:58.281: D/dalvikvm(587): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x06d7 at 0x0c in Ljavax/mail/internet/MimeMessage;.getDataHandler
02-16 23:33:58.293: I/dalvikvm(587): Failed resolving Ljavax/activation/DataHandler; interface 176 'Ljava/awt/datatransfer/Transferable;'
02-16 23:33:58.293: W/dalvikvm(587): Link of class 'Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;' failed
02-16 23:33:58.293: D/dalvikvm(587): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x06d5 at 0x02 in Ljavax/mail/internet/MimeMessage;.setContent
02-16 23:33:58.311: I/dalvikvm(587): Failed resolving Ljavax/activation/DataHandler; interface 176 'Ljava/awt/datatransfer/Transferable;'
02-16 23:33:58.311: W/dalvikvm(587): Link of class 'Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;' failed
02-16 23:33:58.323: D/dalvikvm(587): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x06d5 at 0x06 in Ljavax/mail/internet/MimeMessage;.setContent
02-16 23:33:58.363: D/AndroidRuntime(587): Shutting down VM
02-16 23:33:58.363: W/dalvikvm(587): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
02-16 23:33:58.391: E/AndroidRuntime(587): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-16 23:33:58.391: E/AndroidRuntime(587): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.activation.DataHandler
02-16 23:33:58.391: E/AndroidRuntime(587):  at san.sendmail.improsys.GMailSender.sendMail(GMailSender.java:53)
02-16 23:33:58.391: E/AndroidRuntime(587):  at san.sendmail.improsys.MailSenderActivity$1.onClick(MailSenderActivity.java:25)
02-16 23:33:58.391: E/AndroidRuntime(587):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
02-16 23:33:58.391: E/AndroidRuntime(587):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
02-16 23:33:58.391: E/AndroidRuntime(587):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
02-16 23:33:58.391: E/AndroidRuntime(587):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-16 23:33:58.391: E/AndroidRuntime(587):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-16 23:33:58.391: E/AndroidRuntime(587):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
02-16 23:33:58.391: E/AndroidRuntime(587):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-16 23:33:58.391: E/AndroidRuntime(587):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-16 23:33:58.391: E/AndroidRuntime(587):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-16 23:33:58.391: E/AndroidRuntime(587):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-16 23:33:58.391: E/AndroidRuntime(587):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-16 23:34:10.491: I/Process(587): Sending signal. PID: 587 SIG: 9
02-16 23:37:58.423: D/gralloc_goldfish(665): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
02-16 23:38:36.581: I/dalvikvm(665): Failed resolving Ljavax/activation/DataHandler; interface 176 'Ljava/awt/datatransfer/Transferable;'
02-16 23:38:36.581: W/dalvikvm(665): Link of class 'Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;' failed
02-16 23:38:36.581: E/dalvikvm(665): Could not find class 'javax.activation.DataHandler', referenced from method san.sendmail.improsys.GMailSender.sendMail
02-16 23:38:36.621: W/dalvikvm(665): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 351 (Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;) in Lsan/sendmail/improsys/GMailSender;
02-16 23:38:36.621: D/dalvikvm(665): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0008
02-16 23:38:36.642: I/dalvikvm(665): Failed resolving Ljavax/activation/DataHandler; interface 176 'Ljava/awt/datatransfer/Transferable;'
02-16 23:38:36.642: W/dalvikvm(665): Link of class 'Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;' failed
02-16 23:38:36.662: D/dalvikvm(665): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x06d7 at 0x15 in Lsan/sendmail/improsys/GMailSender;.sendMail
02-16 23:38:36.732: I/dalvikvm(665): Failed resolving Ljavax/activation/DataHandler; interface 176 'Ljava/awt/datatransfer/Transferable;'
02-16 23:38:36.742: W/dalvikvm(665): Link of class 'Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;' failed
02-16 23:38:36.742: W/dalvikvm(665): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;)
02-16 23:38:36.742: I/dalvikvm(665): Failed resolving Ljavax/activation/DataHandler; interface 176 'Ljava/awt/datatransfer/Transferable;'
02-16 23:38:36.742: W/dalvikvm(665): Link of class 'Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;' failed
02-16 23:38:36.742: I/dalvikvm(665): Could not find method javax.activation.DataHandler.getContent, referenced from method javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.getContent
02-16 23:38:36.742: W/dalvikvm(665): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1760: Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;.getContent ()Ljava/lang/Object;
02-16 23:38:36.742: D/dalvikvm(665): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0004
02-16 23:38:36.762: I/dalvikvm(665): Failed resolving Ljavax/activation/DataHandler; interface 176 'Ljava/awt/datatransfer/Transferable;'
02-16 23:38:36.762: W/dalvikvm(665): Link of class 'Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;' failed
02-16 23:38:36.782: I/dalvikvm(665): Failed resolving Ljavax/activation/DataHandler; interface 176 'Ljava/awt/datatransfer/Transferable;'
02-16 23:38:36.782: W/dalvikvm(665): Link of class 'Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;' failed
02-16 23:38:36.782: E/dalvikvm(665): Could not find class 'javax.activation.DataHandler', referenced from method javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.getDataHandler
02-16 23:38:36.782: W/dalvikvm(665): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 351 (Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;) in Ljavax/mail/internet/MimeMessage;
02-16 23:38:36.782: D/dalvikvm(665): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0005
02-16 23:38:36.793: I/dalvikvm(665): Failed resolving Ljavax/activation/DataHandler; interface 176 'Ljava/awt/datatransfer/Transferable;'
02-16 23:38:36.793: W/dalvikvm(665): Link of class 'Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;' failed
02-16 23:38:36.793: I/dalvikvm(665): Failed resolving Ljavax/activation/DataHandler; interface 176 'Ljava/awt/datatransfer/Transferable;'
02-16 23:38:36.793: W/dalvikvm(665): Link of class 'Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;' failed
02-16 23:38:36.802: W/dalvikvm(665): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;)
02-16 23:38:36.802: I/dalvikvm(665): Failed resolving Ljavax/activation/DataHandler; interface 176 'Ljava/awt/datatransfer/Transferable;'
02-16 23:38:36.813: W/dalvikvm(665): Link of class 'Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;' failed
02-16 23:38:36.813: W/dalvikvm(665): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;)
02-16 23:38:36.813: I/dalvikvm(665): Failed resolving Ljavax/activation/DataHandler; interface 176 'Ljava/awt/datatransfer/Transferable;'
02-16 23:38:36.813: W/dalvikvm(665): Link of class 'Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;' failed
02-16 23:38:36.813: I/dalvikvm(665): Could not find method javax.activation.DataHandler.getInputStream, referenced from method javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.getInputStream
02-16 23:38:36.813: W/dalvikvm(665): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1764: Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;.getInputStream ()Ljava/io/InputStream;
02-16 23:38:36.813: D/dalvikvm(665): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0004
02-16 23:38:36.832: I/dalvikvm(665): Failed resolving Ljavax/activation/DataHandler; interface 176 'Ljava/awt/datatransfer/Transferable;'
02-16 23:38:36.832: W/dalvikvm(665): Link of class 'Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;' failed
02-16 23:38:36.832: E/dalvikvm(665): Could not find class 'javax.activation.DataHandler', referenced from method javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.setContent
02-16 23:38:36.832: W/dalvikvm(665): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 351 (Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;) in Ljavax/mail/internet/MimeMessage;
02-16 23:38:36.832: D/dalvikvm(665): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
02-16 23:38:36.842: I/dalvikvm(665): Failed resolving Ljavax/activation/DataHandler; interface 176 'Ljava/awt/datatransfer/Transferable;'
02-16 23:38:36.842: W/dalvikvm(665): Link of class 'Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;' failed
02-16 23:38:36.842: E/dalvikvm(665): Could not find class 'javax.activation.DataHandler', referenced from method javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.setContent
02-16 23:38:36.842: W/dalvikvm(665): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 351 (Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;) in Ljavax/mail/internet/MimeMessage;
02-16 23:38:36.842: D/dalvikvm(665): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
02-16 23:38:36.852: I/dalvikvm(665): Failed resolving Ljavax/activation/DataHandler; interface 176 'Ljava/awt/datatransfer/Transferable;'
02-16 23:38:36.852: W/dalvikvm(665): Link of class 'Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;' failed
02-16 23:38:36.852: W/dalvikvm(665): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;)
02-16 23:38:36.852: I/dalvikvm(665): Failed resolving Ljavax/activation/DataHandler; interface 176 'Ljava/awt/datatransfer/Transferable;'
02-16 23:38:36.852: W/dalvikvm(665): Link of class 'Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;' failed
02-16 23:38:36.892: I/dalvikvm(665): Failed resolving Ljavax/activation/DataHandler; interface 176 'Ljava/awt/datatransfer/Transferable;'
02-16 23:38:36.892: W/dalvikvm(665): Link of class 'Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;' failed
02-16 23:38:36.892: D/dalvikvm(665): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x06d7 at 0x0c in Ljavax/mail/internet/MimeMessage;.getDataHandler
02-16 23:38:36.892: I/dalvikvm(665): Failed resolving Ljavax/activation/DataHandler; interface 176 'Ljava/awt/datatransfer/Transferable;'
02-16 23:38:36.892: W/dalvikvm(665): Link of class 'Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;' failed
02-16 23:38:36.902: D/dalvikvm(665): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x06d5 at 0x02 in Ljavax/mail/internet/MimeMessage;.setContent
02-16 23:38:36.902: I/dalvikvm(665): Failed resolving Ljavax/activation/DataHandler; interface 176 'Ljava/awt/datatransfer/Transferable;'
02-16 23:38:36.902: W/dalvikvm(665): Link of class 'Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;' failed
02-16 23:38:36.902: D/dalvikvm(665): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x06d5 at 0x06 in Ljavax/mail/internet/MimeMessage;.setContent
02-16 23:38:36.933: D/AndroidRuntime(665): Shutting down VM
02-16 23:38:36.933: W/dalvikvm(665): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
02-16 23:38:36.951: E/AndroidRuntime(665): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-16 23:38:36.951: E/AndroidRuntime(665): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.activation.DataHandler
02-16 23:38:36.951: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at san.sendmail.improsys.GMailSender.sendMail(GMailSender.java:53)
02-16 23:38:36.951: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at san.sendmail.improsys.MailSenderActivity$1.onClick(MailSenderActivity.java:25)
02-16 23:38:36.951: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
02-16 23:38:36.951: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
02-16 23:38:36.951: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
02-16 23:38:36.951: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-16 23:38:36.951: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-16 23:38:36.951: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
02-16 23:38:36.951: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-16 23:38:36.951: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-16 23:38:36.951: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-16 23:38:36.951: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-16 23:38:36.951: E/AndroidRuntime(665):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Have a look at this question - it may have what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368704/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-activation-datahandler-in-android

Comment: post the offending code in san.sendmail.improsys.GMailSender.sendmail. You need some error handling for the call you're making.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to check your project setup/definition - it attempts to load javax.activation.DataHandler class, which is not a part of the SDK. Is it what you intended?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that not every single class that works fine in Java will work on Android, as it first has to be transformed to the format accepted by Dalvik, the JVM variation for Android. so, some classes (such as classes belonging to javax.*, aspects, etc...) will not be "translatable" and will fail. Consider using only the minimum set of classes accepted by the Android VM.