# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.activation.DataHandler

Tags: android, jakarta-mail, noclassdeffounderror, datahandler

I'm facing a problem with my android project, basically I'm trying to send an email and got the error:

```
public class ConnectEmail {
    private Session session;
    private Properties properties;
    private final String password;
    private final String username;

    public ConnectEmail(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public boolean getSession() {
        boolean result = false;
        properties = getProperties();
        try {
            session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties,
                    new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                            return new PasswordAuthentication(username,
                                    password);
                        }
                    });
            Log.i("Check", "Got session");
            result = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString() + "Session: Unknown Exception");
        }

        return result;
    }

    public Properties getProperties() {

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        Log.i("Check", "Got properties");
        return props;
    }

    public void sendEmail(String recipients, String subject, String content) {
        String finalString = "";

        boolean result = getSession();

        if (result) {
            try {
                Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
                message.setDataHandler(handler);
                Log.i("Check", "creating message");

                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                        InternetAddress.parse(recipients));
                message.setSubject(subject);
                message.setText(content);

                 Log.i("check", "transport");
                    Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
                    Log.i("check", "connecting");
                    transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com",username , password);
                    Log.i("check", "wana send");
                    transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
                    transport.close();

                    Log.i("check", "sent");



            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);

        }} else
            System.out.println("Invalid session...");

    }
}
```

And my LogCat says:

```
11-16 15:33:38.000: E/AndroidRuntime(19426): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-16 15:33:38.000: E/AndroidRuntime(19426): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.activation.DataHandler
11-16 15:33:38.000: E/AndroidRuntime(19426):    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.setContent(MimeMessage.java:1454)
11-16 15:33:38.000: E/AndroidRuntime(19426):    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.setText(MimeBodyPart.java:1075)
11-16 15:33:38.000: E/AndroidRuntime(19426):    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.setText(MimeMessage.java:1493)
11-16 15:33:38.000: E/AndroidRuntime(19426):    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.setText(MimeMessage.java:1477)
11-16 15:33:38.000: E/AndroidRuntime(19426):    at com.example.emailontime.control.ConnectEmail.sendEmail(ConnectEmail.java:83)
11-16 15:33:38.000: E/AndroidRuntime(19426):    at com.example.emailontime.activities.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:45)
11-16 15:33:38.000: E/AndroidRuntime(19426):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
11-16 15:33:38.000: E/AndroidRuntime(19426):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17362)
11-16 15:33:38.000: E/AndroidRuntime(19426):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
11-16 15:33:38.000: E/AndroidRuntime(19426):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-16 15:33:38.000: E/AndroidRuntime(19426):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-16 15:33:38.000: E/AndroidRuntime(19426):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
11-16 15:33:38.000: E/AndroidRuntime(19426):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-16 15:33:38.000: E/AndroidRuntime(19426):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-16 15:33:38.000: E/AndroidRuntime(19426):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
11-16 15:33:38.000: E/AndroidRuntime(19426):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
11-16 15:33:38.000: E/AndroidRuntime(19426):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I saw some questions and people usually says that the problem is in the build path, I tried to reinstall the mail.jar, clean the project but nothing.
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.activation.DataHandler in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368704/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-activation-datahandler-in-android)

Comment: @aegean Not helped... Still got the same error

Comment: The class is either missing or there is a conflict. This could help you out - http://javareferencegv.blogspot.com/2013/10/debugging-javalangnoclassdeffounderror.html

Answer (score 3):

Android isn't Java.  Please complain to Google.  Tell them that Android should be Java Compatible.

In the mean time, if you've added [additionnal.jar](http://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/downloads/detail?name=additionnal.jar&can=2&q=) and [activation.jar](http://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/downloads/detail?name=activation.jar&can=2&q=) to your application (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368704/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-activation-datahandler-in-android)) and it's still not working, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: I had this problem when I imported just  activation.jar, importing additionnal.jar worked FOR ME.

Comment: Note that there is now an official [JavaMail for Android](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Android).

Answer (score 1):

Update :

official JavaMail for Android https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Android

old unofficial version : Javamail for android
https://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/

Thanks [Bill Shannon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1040885/bill-shannon)

Comment: This is an old unofficial version.  There is now an official [JavaMail for Android](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Android).