# Basic email not working

Tags: java, android, email, android-studio, importerror

Simple emailer is saying it couldn't execute the method, despite the fact I have the libary for it and internet access allowed. Not sure what could be wrong, and I would appreciate any advice. Here's the code, manifest, and xml. Thanks for any help, I'm mainly self taught and this is being a pain.

Activity:

```
package comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;


/**
 * An example full-screen activity that shows and hides the system UI (i.e.
 * status bar and navigation/system bar) with user interaction.
 */
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {
    /**
     * Whether or not the system UI should be auto-hidden after
     * {@link #AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS} milliseconds.
     */





    private static final boolean AUTO_HIDE = true;

    /**
     * If {@link #AUTO_HIDE} is set, the number of milliseconds to wait after
     * user interaction before hiding the system UI.
     */
    private static final int AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS = 3000;

    /**
     * Some older devices needs a small delay between UI widget updates
     * and a change of the status and navigation bar.
     */
    private static final int UI_ANIMATION_DELAY = 300;

    private View mContentView;
    private View mControlsView;
    private boolean mVisible;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        mVisible = true;
        mControlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
        mContentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);


        // Set up the user interaction to manually show or hide the system UI.
        mContentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                toggle();
            }
        });

        // Upon interacting with UI controls, delay any scheduled hide()
        // operations to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
        // while interacting with the UI.
        findViewById(R.id.btnSay).setOnTouchListener(mDelayHideTouchListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Trigger the initial hide() shortly after the activity has been
        // created, to briefly hint to the user that UI controls
        // are available.
        delayedHide(100);
    }

    /**
     * Touch listener to use for in-layout UI controls to delay hiding the
     * system UI. This is to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
     * while interacting with activity UI.
     */
    private final View.OnTouchListener mDelayHideTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (AUTO_HIDE) {
                delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    private void toggle() {
        if (mVisible) {
            hide();
        } else {
            show();
        }
    }

    private void hide() {
        // Hide UI first
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.hide();
        }
        mControlsView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mVisible = false;

        // Schedule a runnable to remove the status and navigation bar after a delay
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mShowPart2Runnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHidePart2Runnable, UI_ANIMATION_DELAY);
    }

    private final Runnable mHidePart2Runnable = new Runnable() {
        @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Delayed removal of status and navigation bar

            // Note that some of these constants are new as of API 16 (Jelly Bean)
            // and API 19 (KitKat). It is safe to use them, as they are inlined
            // at compile-time and do nothing on earlier devices.
            mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
        }
    };

    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    private void show() {
        // Show the system bar
        mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
        mVisible = true;

        // Schedule a runnable to display UI elements after a delay
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHidePart2Runnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mShowPart2Runnable, UI_ANIMATION_DELAY);
    }

    private final Runnable mShowPart2Runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Delayed display of UI elements
            ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            if (actionBar != null) {
                actionBar.show();
            }
            mControlsView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    };

    private final Handler mHideHandler = new Handler();
    private final Runnable mHideRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            hide();
        }
    };

    /**
     * Schedules a call to hide() in [delay] milliseconds, canceling any
     * previously scheduled calls.
     */
    private void delayedHide(int delayMillis) {
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHideRunnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHideRunnable, delayMillis);
    }
        public void evaluateInput(View v) {
            final EditText Input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtInput); //Lets textbox be referenced
            final TextView Output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblOutput); //Lets label be referenced
            final RelativeLayout homeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.homeInterface);

            final RelativeLayout emailLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.emailInterface);

            String strInput; // Gets textbox string
            strInput = Input.getText().toString();
            strInput = strInput.toLowerCase();
//Commands:
            if (strInput.contains("open browser")) {
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai.Browser.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
            } else if (strInput.contains("send email")) {
                    homeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    emailLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            if ((strInput.contains("hello")) || (strInput.contains(" hi "))) {
                Output.setText("Hello");
            } else if ((strInput.contains("you") && strInput.contains("are")) && (strInput.contains("idiot") || strInput.contains("stupid") || strInput.contains("retard") || strInput.contains("dumb") || strInput.contains("you're") && strInput.contains("idiot") || strInput.contains("stupid") || strInput.contains("retard") || strInput.contains("dumb"))) {
                Output.setText("I'm sorry to dissapoint you");
            } else if (strInput.contains("goodbye") || strInput.contains("bye")) {
                Output.setText("Farewell");
            } else if (strInput.contains("shut up")) {
                Output.setText(("Anything for you"));
            } else if (strInput.contains("do you like doctor who?")) {
                Output.setText("I'll take joy in it if you do");
            } else if (strInput.contains("what is the answer to life the universe and everything")) {
                Output.setText("42");
            } else if (strInput.contains("tell me something nice")) {
                Output.setText("You look nice today");
                Output.setTextSize(5);
                Output.append("...says the AI with no eyes");
                Output.setTextSize(16);
            } else if (strInput.contains("will you marry me")) {
                Output.setText("I'm sorry but I don't have the capacity for marriage");
            } else if (strInput.contains("where can I hide a body")) {
                Output.setText(("That isn't my area of expertise"));
            } else if (strInput.contains("weather is nice")) {
                Output.setText(("If you say so"));
            } else if (strInput.contains("bitch") || strInput.contains("fuck") || strInput.contains("shit") || strInput.contains("damn") || strInput.contains("ass")) {
                Output.setText(("Please try to be a little more intelligent"));
            } else if (strInput.contains("what is your name")) {
                Output.setText(("Ignis"));
            } else if (strInput.contains("who created you")) {
                Output.setText(("Prometheus created me"));
            } else if (strInput.contains("who is prometheus")) {
                Output.setText(("Prometheus is the one who created Ignis"));
            } else if (strInput.contains("whats up") || strInput.contains("what's up") || strInput.contains("wassup")) {
                Output.setText(("Whatever I need do for you"));
            } else if (strInput.contains("are you a boy or a girl") || strInput.contains("are you a girl or a boy")) {
                Output.setText(("Neither"));
            } else if (strInput.contains("who are you") || strInput.contains("what are you")) {
                Output.setText(("I am myself"));
            } else if (strInput.contains("i'm hungry") || strInput.contains("i am hungry")) {
                Output.setText("I'm sorry to hear that");
            } else if (strInput.contains("good morning")) {
                Output.setText(("Good morning to you too"));
            } else if (strInput.contains("good night")) {
                Output.setText(("Good night"));
            } else if (strInput.contains("how are you")) {
                Output.setText(("I'm existing and functioning well, and you?"));
            } else if (strInput.contains("do you like") || strInput.contains("what do you think about")) {
                Output.setText(("Frankly I don't have an opinion on the matter"));
            } else if (strInput.contains("what is the meaning of life")) {
                Output.setText(("To live while you can I would guess"));
            }


        }


    public void SendEmail(View view) {


        final EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUser);
        final String User = username.getText().toString();
        final EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPass);
        final String Pass = password.getText().toString();
        final EditText toEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtTo);
        final String ToEmail = toEmail.getText().toString();
        final EditText body = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtBody);
        final String Body = body.getText().toString();
        System.out.println(Body);
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                new Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(User, Pass);
                    }
                });

        try {

            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(User));
            message.setRecipients(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse(ToEmail));
            message.setSubject("Sent from Ignis AI");
            message.setText(Body);

            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    }
```

Xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="#0099cc" tools:context=".Browser">

    <!-- The primary full-screen view. This can be replaced with whatever view
         is needed to present your content, e.g. VideoView, SurfaceView,
         TextureView, etc. -->
    <TextView android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:keepScreenOn="true" android:textColor="#33b5e5"
        android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="50sp" android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#000000" android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />

    <!-- This FrameLayout insets its children based on system windows using
         android:fitsSystemWindows. -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:textColor="#33b5e5"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls" />

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/homeInterface"
        android:visibility="invisible">

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/say"
            android:id="@+id/btnSay"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:onClick="evaluateInput"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Ignis:"
            android:id="@+id/lblIgnis"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:textColor="#FFB77C06" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:id="@+id/lblOutput"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/lblIgnis"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lblIgnis"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnSay"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/btnSay"
            android:textColor="#FFB77C06"
            android:layout_above="@+id/btnSay"
            android:editable="false"
            android:text="Awaiting input."
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtInput"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnSay"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnSay"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnSay"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:editable="true"
            android:clickable="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/emailInterface">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Send Email"
            android:id="@+id/btnEmail"
            android:onClick="SendEmail"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="  Gmail Emailer"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:textColor="#FFB77C06" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="  Your Username  "
            android:id="@+id/lblUser"
            android:textColor="#FFB77C06"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtUser"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/lblUser"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lblUser"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnEmail"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnEmail"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:inputType="text" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="  Your Password  "
            android:id="@+id/lblPass"
            android:textColor="#FFB77C06"
            android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtUser"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtPass"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/lblPass"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtUser"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txtUser"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtUser"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/txtUser"
            android:inputType="text" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="  Send to  "
            android:id="@+id/lblSendTo"
            android:textColor="#FFB77C06"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lblPass"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtTo"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/lblSendTo"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtPass"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txtPass"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtPass"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/txtPass"
            android:inputType="text" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="  Subject  "
            android:id="@+id/lblSubject"
            android:textColor="#FFB77C06"
            android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtTo"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtSubject"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/lblSubject"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lblPass"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtTo"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/txtTo"
            android:inputType="text" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="  Body  "
            android:id="@+id/lblBody"
            android:textColor="#FFB77C06"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text|textMultiLine"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/txtBody"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/lblBody"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtTo"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txtTo"
            android:layout_above="@+id/btnEmail"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnEmail"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/btnEmail" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Browser"/>
        <activity android:name=".ConnectorActivity"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile files('libs/javax.mail.jar')
    compile files('libs/activation-1.1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
    compile files('libs/javax.mail-1.5.4.jar')
}
```

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: It's exceeeding the limit, one second,.

Comment: put it here: http://pastebin.com/XFtbJeBd

Comment: Can you put up your gradle build file?  Perhaps you're not including the dependencies properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see in your stacktrace the reason why it's not working.

```
11-14 02:54:01.475 5398-5398/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.activation.DataHandler
11-14 02:54:01.475 5398-5398/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.setContent(MimeMessage.java:1515)
11-14 02:54:01.475 5398-5398/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.setText(MimeBodyPart.java:1170)
11-14 02:54:01.475 5398-5398/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.setText(MimeMessage.java:1554)
11-14 02:54:01.475 5398-5398/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.setText(MimeMessage.java:1538)
```

How to resolve this error has already been answered in this thread on SO:

[java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.activation.DataHandler in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368704/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-activation-datahandler-in-android)

Comment: Thanks, I used a tutorial for installing the mail lib and classpath (I'm extremely new to this) and they never mentioned the activation jar, which is why it confused me. Anyway, thanks man.

Comment: Ok, still an error. I put the jar in the classpath, added as libary, but when I put down "import javax.activation.DataHandler;" as soon  as I click somewhere else it deletes from the code

Comment: Do you have java-> editor -> save actions -> organize imports enabled in Eclipse preferences? If so, disable checkbox for a moment and check whether you have any compiler error in import statement.

Comment: I'm using android studio

Comment: Note: Trying to "import javax.activation.*;" deletes too

Comment: maybe try edit java file in text file editor (like Notepad) and then reopen android studio.

Comment: Hmmm I'll try in Dr.Java (Very simple API, pretty much a text editor with output screen)

Comment: That *somewhat* worked. However, when I opened up android studio, it didn't delete the import. It simply greyed it out, and still gives me the "Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.activation.DataHandler" message

Comment: Reminds me of the whole "99 little bugs in the code" song...The emailer and independent web browser are some of this app's nicer functions (It's new, and I'm new to making it) and they're also my favorite...but both are giving me a lot of trouble

Comment: I am sorry, I am not familiar with android studio so will not help you. Consider adding more tags to the question and edit it with new informations