# NoClassDefFoundError Exception in AsyncTask

Tags: android

I am using java.mail API from Oracle in my AsyncTask, the program compiles properly but when I try to test on an emulator, the app just crashes and I get this error. I have the correct stuff in my build.gradle file. I'm not sure whats going on.

compile 'javax.mail:javax.mail-api:1.5.6'

```
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart$MimePartDataHandler>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;
I/art:     at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.Object, dalvik.system.DexFile) (DexFile.java:-2)
I/art:     at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.Object, dalvik.system.DexFile, java.util.List) (DexFile.java:296)
```

Comment: is it a compatible version for android?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368704/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-activation-datahandler-in-android

Comment: I just tried that thread you linked, still the same problem.