# DataFlavor class not found using BouncyCastle for Android

Tags: android, jakarta-mail, bouncycastle

I have successfully imported *BouncyCastle* into my Android project and added the *javamail* for android packages to my project [here.](https://code.google.com/archive/p/javamail-android/)

I'm now having an issue when trying to sign a file, *BouncyCastle* try to access a class called `DataFlavor`, located into the `java.awt.datatransfer` package.

I've read on some posts that, in my case, the class is located into `myjava.awt.datatransfer` , in additional jar of *Javamail* for `android`

So I modified the sources of *BouncyCastle* jar to access this class, but unfortunately this didn't work, now it tells me that it

> "cannot convert from ActivationDataFlavor to DataFlavor".

Does anyone knows how can I solve this issue ? 
Help will be appreciated!

**Edit**

Here is the complete stacktrace when app crashes

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   [Ljava/awt/datatransfer/DataFlavor;
>                                                                                             at org.bouncycastle.mail.smime.handlers.pkcs7_mime.(Unknown
>   Source:16)
>                                                                                             at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
>                                                                                             at
>   javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap.getDataContentHandler(MailcapCommandMap.java:609)
>                                                                                             at
>   javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap.createDataContentHandler(MailcapCommandMap.java:563)
>                                                                                             at
>   javax.activation.DataHandler.getDataContentHandler(DataHandler.java:626)
>                                                                                             at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:329)
>                                                                                             at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1692)
>                                                                                             at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:996)

Comment: This has nothing to do with bouncycastle, which does not make reference to that class.

Comment: BouncyCastle calls this class when I use "SMIMESignedGenerator.generateEncapsulated()"

Comment: Post the complete stacktrace showing this.

Comment: I have updated my question, so you can see it there

Comment: Ah, the mail package. Are you using the spongycastle jars (com.magdag.spongycastle)?

Comment: No I don't, I'm using the bouncycastle jars only, I tried creating another project with spongycastle, but the class SMIMESignedGenerator exists only into bouncycastle jar

Comment: It sounds like you need the spongycastle jars rather than the bouncycastle jars. I don't know why the scmail jars aren't in maven, but perhaps you can pay rtyley to produce a scmail jar for 1.58. He accepts bitcoin as of a couple of years ago.

Comment: [Use the official JavaMail that has a special build for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368704/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-activation-datahandler-in-android/37010429#37010429)

Comment: Hi @jmehrens , I've just tried using this javamail that you sent me, now I'm getting another error, at another place in the code, your help will be appreciated, here's what I het, an ExceptionInInitializerError with message java.lang.ArrayStoreException: javax.activation.ActivationDataFlavor cannot be stored in an array of type java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor[]